# Change slider height in wordpress theme Make

Tags: css, wordpress, slider

I am trying to change the page builder banner (slider) height in the Wordpress theme Make.
It will let me change the width of the slider, but for some reason the height is frozen. Below bit of code is where I change the width, I would assume that's where the height is to be changed as well?

```
    .builder-banner-slide {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding previously defined height property value as shown below.

```
height: 0!important; /* Adjust as needed */
overflow: hidden!important; /* Hide whatever part that goes beyond the given height */
```

Your code will now look like below

```
 .builder-banner-slide {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 100%;
     height: 0!important; /* Adjust as needed */
     overflow: hidden!important; /* Hide whatever part that goes beyond the given height */
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;
     background-size: cover; }
```

Note: if the above doesn't do it, check if you have the correct id or class of the containing element.